# Is there a simple (free) way to encrypt an excel workbook in python?

Tags: python, excel, security, encryption, passwords

I need to automate sending of a number of Excel Workbooks but have slight concerns about security. I would like to password protect each workbook before they are delivered. This encryption process would need to occur in python

Is there a simple way of doing it? I've come across Openpyxl, however, the password protection doesn't seem to work fully. i.e. no password is required on opening.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

test_spreadsheet = "test.xlsx"

wb = Workbook()
wb.security.workbookPassword = 'password'
wb.security.lockStructure = True
wb.save(test_spreadsheet)
```

Comment: Can't you zip/archive the file with a password? That seems more robust and standard that relying on Excel encryption